# OutOfMemoryError when restart my Kafka Streams appplication

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams app(Kafka Streams 2.1 + Kafka broker 2.0) which does a aggregation based on TimeWindows, and I use the suppress operator to supress the result's output.

Everything works well until I restart my app, it will reset the offset of KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE to 0 to restore the suppression state, as expected. But each time I restart it, it will throw an `OutOfMemoryError`, I thought maybe the heap size is not enough, so I use a larger `Xmx/Xms`, it works one or two restart, and then the `OutOfMemoryError` comes back again. Now the `Xmx` is about 20G now, I think something is not right here.

The code snippet:

```
TimeWindows windows = TimeWindows.of(windowSize).until(retentionHours.toMillis()).grace(graceHours);

KTable<Windowed<String>, MyStatistics> kTable = groupedBySerialNumber
                .windowedBy(windows)
                .aggregate(MyStatistics::new,
                    (sn, resList, stats) -> stats.addResources(resList).updateSN(sn),
                    Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), ArchiveSerdes.resourceStatistics()))
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(timeToWait, Suppressed.BufferConfig.maxBytes(bufferMaxBytes)));
```

And I find that the key of record in KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE is something like 1234567j�P, which is not readable, but I guess it's generated by combine the SN and window, I think this will make KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE redundent, because each SN will have multi records for each window.

I have two questions:

1. If the `OutOfMemoryError` indicates a small heap size or not, if so, how to limit the rate, if not, what does it means?
2. The key for KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE is defined by which API, how or should can I control it?

Thanks!

**Edit in 2019/4/16**

The error stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space        
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)        
        at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)        
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:112)        
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:381)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:342)        
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:609)        
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:541)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467)        
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:535)        
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1243)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1188)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StoreChangelogReader.restore(StoreChangelogReader.java:88)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.updateNewAndRestoringTasks(TaskManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:839)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:777)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:747)
```

Answer (score 3):

> If the OutOfMemoryError indicates a small heap size or not, if so, how to limit the rate, if not, what does it means?

Yes, there's not enough heap to allocate all the memory that the application needs to operate. We don't see this very often, and the suppression operator is new, so I'm suspicious of it, but it's good to bear in mind that basically any data structure in your application could be responsible.

The best way to diagnose memory pressure is to do a "heap dump". This basically copies your JVM's entire memory into a file, so that you can analyse its contents using a program like https://www.eclipse.org/mat/ . It'll be a little bit of a learning curve, but I think you'll find that some facility with analyzing memory usage is very handy in general.

You can trigger a heap dump at any time (there are several ways to do it, you'll have to research the best way for you). But I think you'll want to make use of Java's nifty option to do a heap dump when it gets an out-of-memory error. This way, you're more likely to positively identify the culprit. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbzrr , or similar for your JVM.

I can speculate about the cause of the heap dump, but I'm afraid I might just lead you astray and waste your time. Once you have the results of the dump, I think you should go ahead and open a bug report in the Kafka issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA . Then, we can help figure out both how to work around the bug to get you running again, and also how to fix it in future releases.

Actually, I will offer one speculation... It's possible you're seeing a result of this bug: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/6536 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7895) . If your OOME goes away when you remove the suppression operator, you might want to leave it out for now. As soon as we merge the fix, I'll request a bugfix release, and you can try again to see if the problem is resolved.

> The key for KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE is defined by which API, how or should can I control it?

Fortunately, this has a more straightforward answer. The key you're looking at is a binary-packed version of your record key and the timestamp of the window. This key is a result of your usage of `windowBy`. In Java, you can see that the result of the aggregation is a `KTable<Windowed<String>, ...>` and that Suppress doesn't change the key or value type. In other words, you're looking at a serialized version of the key (`Windowed<String>`).

Leaving suppression aside for a second; Let's say you have two serial numbers, "asdf" and "zxcv". Let's say your window size is one hour. Your application is grouping events for *each* of those serial numbers (independently) in each hour of the day. So there's an aggregation for all the "asdf" records from 9:00 to 10:00, and there's also one for all the "zxcv" records from 9:00 to 10:00. Thus, the total number of keys in the windowed KTable is `key space` x `number of windows being retained` .

The Suppression operator will have no effect on the number of keys in the KTable. Its purpose is to suppress *updates* to those keys for a specified amount of time (`timeToWait`). For example, without suppress, if you get 3 updates to the "asdf" record between 9:00 and 10:00, the windowed aggregation will emit an updated result for `(asdf, 9:00)` each time, so for 3 events in, you see 3 result updates coming out. The Suppress operator just prevents those result updates until `timeToWait` has passed, and when it does pass, it emits only the most recent update.

So, the number of keys in the suppression buffer at any time is smaller than the total number of keys in the upstream KTable. It just contains the keys that have been updated in the last `timeToWait` amount of time.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much John, your explanation is very helpful!   For the first question, I have added `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to JVM to further investigation, yestoday I deleted the SUPPRESS topics, and everything seems OK for now and I will observe it for several days if it happened again, I will report it to Kafka community.  For the second question, there is still one thing unclear to me, say, if I have two serial number, "abc" and "efg", the window size is 1 hour, then the SUPPRESS topic will have 2 * 24 records, even several days passed, since the SUPPRESS topic is compact log, right?

Comment: One more thing, since record key in SUPPRESS topic is a serialized `Window<String>`, it will contains the start time and end time, then for a record of 9:00-10:00, it's key stays unchaged for every day? I guess each key's start time and end time is different for every day, could you help calirify these? Thanks!

Comment: No problem, songkun. The suppression operator emits a tombstone to the changelog topic as soon as it emits the result, so the topic (like the buffer) only has non-tombstoned records for the "live" window-keys. If you have 1-hour windows, with a 10 minute grace period (for example), and you have those two keys, then you only have 4 non-tombstoned records at any time. (because there are two live windows at any time).

Comment: For the second question, I was writing in simplified terms for human readability. The serialized Windowed Key contains the bytes for the key, and also the unique start time for that window, in milliseconds since the start of the unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). So the window start times are actually unique between days.

Comment: Thank your reply John. Have read this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7895?focusedCommentId=16810770&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel), I guess I have encountered the same problem, the SUPPRESS topic is becomming larger and larger when I restart, after this patch version is released, I will use it to validate my guess.

Comment: Yep, songkun, That's my theory... That the tombstones are being sent to the wrong partition, so when you restart and replay the changelog, you're missing the deletes, which causes your state stores to grow much larger than they ever were before restarting.