# Out of Memory Issue suspecting due to suppress feature

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Currently using DSL kafka streaming(2.1.1) suppress feature to store intermediate aggregation results.

Application gets continuous streaming and responsible for day window aggregation.

Application runs on total 9 servers, each server has enough memory(64 GB) and disk space(500GB) and also explicitly assign 21 GB memory for only aggregation service though it crashes with OOM issue.

Suppress Topic Defination:application-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog PartitionCount:100 ReplicationFactor:5 Configs:cleanup.policy=compact

My understanding of Suppress operator is as below

1) Suppress does not have statestore but it relays on buffer memory which is backed by change log topic.

2) When Suppress operator emits final results, per many forums it does send tombstone to corresponding change log topic and thus it gets deleted.

but other hand  clean up policy  for this change log topic is only **compact** so not very sure how does it works.

Application is rolled out in the production few days back and observing OOM issue very frequently.

Below is observation..

1) Disk Space is growing very as older window records are not getting deleted from application-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog.

2) Once node get OOM and upon restart cached memory does fills up very quickly by aggregation service .. 18-20 GB which is not anticipated based on low volume.

3)Observed that underneath changelog topic(application-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000004-changelog) for suppress feature does not have retention period by default and it is emitting older records even window has already advanced. Observed when node is crashed due to memory issue and restarted again. Wondering why changelog still kept older window records even window is closed after day? probably clean.policy is only compact?

I am using kafka streaming 2.1.1 version and found a bug registered with kafka stream which is fixed in 2.2.1 and later releases.

[OutOfMemoryError when restart my Kafka Streams appplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690662/outofmemoryerror-when-restart-my-kafka-streams-appplication)

[Kafka Streams State Store Unrecoverable from Change Log Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726224/kafka-streams-state-store-unrecoverable-from-change-log-topic)

In order to re-mediate issue I am planning below.

1) Reset kafka stream with reset application tool which delete internal topics..
2) Clean kafka statestore.
3) Upgrade kafka streaming version to 2.4.0 hoping it is stable.

Please let me know if you have other views on OOM issue.

Sudo code:

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregateTable =
                transactions
                        .groupByKey()
                        .windowedBy(
                                TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(windowDuration)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(windowGraceDuration)))
                        .aggregate(() -> new AggregationService().initialize(),
                                (key, transaction, previousStats) -> new AggregationService().buildAggregation(key, transaction, previousStats, runByUnit),
                                Materialized.<String, JsonNode, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(statStoreName).withRetention(Duration.ofSeconds((windowDuration + windowGraceDuration + windowRetentionDuration)))
                                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                        .withValueSerde(jsonSerde))
                        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Log compaction does also delete data (cf. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) of the last record is a tombstone. For memory management check out https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html -- Is your window is one day, I don't think that retention time is the problem per-se. You should really estimate how much keys you have per day to estimate how much memory you need. For the bug that `suppress()` emits multiple times, you need to upgrade to get the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I am using kafka streaming 2.1.1 version and found a bug related with suppress which later resolved into 2.2.1 and later releases.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KAFKA-7895

Please let me know if 2.3.o can solved this issue?

Observed similler issue Suppress emitting records which were belongs to older window multiple times mainly after restarting node and Out of memory issue is related considering high volume(older and current window records)